# How to get event bindings to work on jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm transferring a normal site to jQuery mobile. I've got some of event bindings, as well as other page specific adjustments:

```
$('.roulette-img').css({
});

$('.shuffle-img').each(function(){
});

$('.button').bind('mousedown', function(){
});

$('.spin-btn').bind('mousedown', function(){
    $(document).bind('mouseup', function(){
    });
})

$(window).resize(function(){
});
```

Right now certain pages don't work as they should (by not firing these events). I understand this is because of jQuery's ajax navigation, that the script only loads once when the first page is loaded and as a result all subsequent content loaded in via AJAX doesn't get binded to events.

Which way is the best to get around it?

Comment: Does the code in your question reside in a `ready` handler?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It resides in a self invoking function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use bind, it is deprecated and removed from jQuery versions 1.9 +. Use on instead. Here's an example:

```
$('#buttonID').on('click', function(){       

});
```

Also if you want to execute something inside a certain page you need to do it inside a jQuery Mobile page event, like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       

});
```

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8hKe2/

Here you can see what it looks to use page events to execute a code for specific pages.

everything you want to know can be found in this answer/article: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**

Comment: Thank you, absolutely fantastic article. Extremely in depth and exactly what I needed. Take care.

Comment: @Gajotres, IIRC we already debated this before, but don't you think binding to `pagebeforeshow` instead of `pageinit` can result in the `mousedown` handlers being bound multiple times if a page is hidden then shown again?

Comment: This is just an example. No point in explaining everything when I have other article describing this in great detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600, same article that's posted in my answer.

Comment: Also, `bind()` is neither deprecated nor removed. `on()` arguably supersedes it, but `bind()` and `unbind()` can still be used. Were you thinking about `live()` and `die()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your handlers to be bound to new pages as they're loaded, you can use the [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) event and restrict your selectors to the page that is currently initialized:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(e) {
    $(".button", e.target).on("mousedown", function() {
        // ...
    });

    $(".spin-btn", e.target).on("mousedown", function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```